# for loop to remove values not in an array in python

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I have a set of images in a numpy array. After some processing and applying a threshold I turned them into images that have either value 0 or 1 in each xy coordinate. I want to use a for loop and nonzero to turn the xy coordinates of the original image that are not in the nonzero array to zero and leave the pixels in the nonzero array with their original intensity. Im a complete noob in programming and I have been given this task.

This is what I have so far but the last part doesn't work:

```
import cv2
# Taking the first image of the data
image = series_copy2[0,:,:]

# Mean total background of the image
print('Mean total background = ' +str(np.mean(image)) + ' counts.')



# Threshold for background removal
threshold =30



# Setting all pixels below a threshold to zero to remove the background
image[image[:,:] < threshold] = 0
image[image[:,:]>threshold]=1

# Plotting the result for checking
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
data = image
plt.tight_layout()
im = plt.imshow(data, interpolation = 'nearest')

np.transpose(np.nonzero(data))

nz_arrays=np.transpose(np.nonzero(data))

#this doesn't work
for x in data:
    if image[image[:,:] not in nz_arrays]=0


# Plotting the result for checking
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
data = image
plt.tight_layout()
im = plt.imshow(data, interpolation = 'nearest')
```

Comment: Hi Pablo. Please try to narrow in on exactly where the program is going wrong, and then provide a minimal complete example that illustrates your problem. This will make it easier for us to understand your issue and provide and answer.

Comment: I wrote "this doesnt work" on top of the loop that gives an error.
I dont understand what you mean with minimal complete example.
What I want the code to do is to compare the original and the "binary" image and put a zero where the binary image has a zero and leave the original image as it is where the binary image has a 1. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
#this doesn't work
for x in data:
    if image[image[:,:] not in nz_arrays] is 0:
    # What is this doing?
```

When using if, you need to end it with a colon and then write the function.

Comment: check the comments maybe it helps you understand what I want to do. Thanks